# Cypress avoid waiting for background image loading

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, cypress

I am writing a test for a login page:

```
cy.visit(loginUrl);
//   type username and password
cy.get('#user').type(email);
cy.get('#password').type(password);
cy.get('#submit').click();
```

But I can see even though the text boxes are visible, cypress does not start the test until the background image is loaded.
The background image is a bit bulky which takes time to load and hence test has to wait long to finish the login.

How can I make Cypress to not wait for the background image to load and start typing if the text boxes are available?

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/440

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stub the background image with an intercept.

If I make a sample site that displays a large nasa image:
`https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA15985/PIA15985~orig.jpg` it takes about 2 second to load.

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA15985/PIA15985~orig.jpg" />
</body>
```

```js
cy.viewport(1500,2000)

Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
  command: 'Network.clearBrowserCache',
})

const start = Date.now()
cy.visit(url).then(() => {
  expect(Date.now() - start).to.be.greaterThan(1500)
})
```

[image]

---

Adding an intercept with fixture, loading off local disc it takes about 200ms.

```js
cy.viewport(1500,2000)

Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
  command: 'Network.clearBrowserCache',
})

cy.intercept(/PIA15985~orig.jpg/, {fixture: '2560x12932.svg'})

const start = Date.now()
cy.visit(url).then(() => {
  expect(Date.now() - start).to.be.lessThan(500)
})
```

[image]